# How to extract part of cell value across columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, substring

I have a data frame like this:

```r
df1<-structure(list(q006_1 = c("1098686880", "18493806","9892464","96193586",
                               "37723803","13925456","37713534","1085246853"),
                    q006_2 = c("1098160170","89009521","9726314","28076230","63451251",
                               "1090421499","37124019"),
                    q006_3 = c("52118967","41915062","1088245358","79277706","91478662",
                               "80048634")), 
               class=data.frame, row.names = c(NA, -8L)))
```

I know how to extract the last five digits of each number for one column using `substr` in data.table but I want to do it across all columns.

```
n_last <- 5  

df1[, `q006_1`:= substr(q006_1, nchar(q006_1) - n_last + 1, nchar(q006_1))]
```

How can I do this for all columns?

Comment: ```lapply(df1, function(x) stringr::str_sub(x, -6, -1))``` or ```lapply(df1, function(x) sub('.*(?=.{5}$)', '', x, perl=T))```

Comment: `lapply(df1,function(x) sub('.*([0-9]{5}\\b)','\\1',x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table` it can be done like below: (Your sample data was incomplete as the first column had 8, second column had 7 and the third had 6 entries.)

```r
library(data.table)

#or `cols <- names(df1)` if you want to apply it on all columns and this is not just an example
cols <- c("q006_1", "q006_2", "q006_3") 

setDT(df1)[ , (cols):= lapply(.SD, function(x){
                                   sub('.*(?=.{5}$)', '', x, perl=T)}),
             .SDcols = cols][]

#     q006_1 q006_2 q006_3
# 1:  86880  60170  18967
# 2:  93806  09521  15062
# 3:  92464  26314  45358
# 4:  93586  76230  77706
# 5:  23803  51251  78662
# 6:  25456  21499  48634
# 7:  13534  24019  76230
# 8:  46853  76230  76230
```

***Data:***

```r
df1<-structure(list(q006_1 = c("1098686880", "18493806","9892464","96193586",
                               "37723803","13925456","37713534","1085246853"),
                    q006_2 = c("1098160170","89009521","9726314","28076230",
                               "63451251","1090421499","37124019","28076230"),
                    q006_3 = c("52118967","41915062","1088245358","79277706",
                               "91478662","80048634","28076230","28076230")),
                class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Cheers! @M-M  Where can I learn more about this `sub('.*(?=.{5}$)', '', x, perl=T)})`

Comment: You could also do `df1 %>% mutate_all(~ substring(., nchar(.)-4))` or `df1[] <- lapply(df1,  function(x) substring(x, nchar(x)-4))`

Comment: @akrun thanks. This is another possibility using `stringi`: ```df1 %>% mutate_all(~ stringi::stri_sub(.,-5,-1))```